# Reindexing multi index data frame

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a df in which some dates of the time period for each station are missing: How do I fill the missing dates per station and set "Value" to NaN within a multi index df?

The df looks like this:

```
                           LST
Date        Station_Number                
2003-01-01    SWE00137272 -238
2003-01-09    SWE00137272 -172
2003-01-17    SWE00137272 -191
2003-01-25    SWE00137272 -202
2003-02-02    SWE00137272 -297
...                   ...  ...
2020-11-24    GLM00004301 -321
2020-12-02    GLM00004301 -323
2020-12-10    GLM00004301 -347
2020-12-18    GLM00004301 -340
2020-12-26    GLM00004301 -312

[636672 rows x 2 columns]
```

The time span goes from 01.01.2003 until 31.12.2020. I have tried using:

```
stations = stations_polar['Station_Number'].unique()

date_range = pd.date_range(
    start=datetime(2003, 1, 1),
    end=datetime(2020, 12, 31),
    freq='D')

station_date_index = (
    pd.MultiIndex
    .from_product(
        iterables=[stations, date_range],
        names=['Station_Number', 'Date']))

LST_merge=LST_merge.reindex(station_date_index, fill_value='NaN')
```

However I get the output:

```
                          Date  LST Station_Number
Station_Number Date                               
CA002100468    2003-01-01  NaT  NaN            NaN
               2003-01-02  NaT  NaN            NaN
               2003-01-03  NaT  NaN            NaN
               2003-01-04  NaT  NaN            NaN
               2003-01-05  NaT  NaN            NaN
...                        ...  ...            ...
USW00096409    2020-12-27  NaT  NaN            NaN
               2020-12-28  NaT  NaN            NaN
               2020-12-29  NaT  NaN            NaN
               2020-12-30  NaT  NaN            NaN
               2020-12-31  NaT  NaN            NaN
```

Ideally the added dates would be set to NaN in the LST column. The output should look like this:

```
                            LST
Date        Station_Number                 
2003-01-01    SWE00137272 -238
2003-01-02    SWE00137272 NaN
2003-01-03    SWE00137272 NaN
2003-01-04    SWE00137272 NaN
2003-01-05    SWE00137272 NaN
2003-01-06    SWE00137272 NaN
2003-01-07    SWE00137272 NaN
2003-01-08    SWE00137272 NaN
2003-01-09    SWE00137272 -202
2003-01-10    SWE00137272 NaN
...
2020-12-18    GLM00004301 NaN
2020-12-22    GLM00004301 NaN
2020-12-23    GLM00004301 NaN
2020-12-24    GLM00004301 NaN
2020-12-25    GLM00004301 NaN
2020-12-26    GLM00004301 -312
2020-12-27    GLM00004301 NaN
2020-12-28    GLM00004301 NaN
2020-12-29    GLM00004301 NaN
2020-12-30    GLM00004301 NaN
2020-12-31    GLM00004301 NaN
```

- Dots meaning the dates per station continue in a continues time period from 2003 to 2020 per station, added dates are set to NaN.

Comment: kindly share a small sample dataframe, maybe 10, at most 20 rows. complete, small, reproducible dataframe (better if you can share the code to create the dataframe), with the expected output dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

If your input data look like:

```
df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Date,Station_Number,LST
2003-01-01,SWE00137272,-238
2003-01-09,SWE00137272,-172
2003-01-17,SWE00137272,-191
2003-01-25,SWE00137272,-202
2003-02-02,SWE00137272,-297"""),
parse_dates=["Date"], index_col=["Date", "Station_Number"])

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 5 entries, (Timestamp('2003-01-01 00:00:00'), 'SWE00137272') to (Timestamp('2003-02-02 00:00:00'), 'SWE00137272')
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   LST     5 non-null      int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 666.0+ bytes
```

then this should work:

```
>>> df.reindex(station_date_index)
                             LST
Date       Station_Number
2003-01-01 SWE00137272    -238.0
2003-01-02 SWE00137272       NaN
2003-01-03 SWE00137272       NaN
2003-01-04 SWE00137272       NaN
2003-01-05 SWE00137272       NaN
...                          ...
2020-12-27 SWE00137272       NaN
2020-12-28 SWE00137272       NaN
2020-12-29 SWE00137272       NaN
2020-12-30 SWE00137272       NaN
2020-12-31 SWE00137272       NaN

[6575 rows x 1 columns]
```